# Find a folder whatever it location is in Python

Tags: python, directory

I would like to know if it was possible to find a folder with just its name and without its location in Python.

I use the way :

```
'C:/Users/lucas/Desktop/Stage_S10/Partie_Code/Donnees_joueur/Donnees_prevent/Donnees_par_impact/'
```

I would like to change it to:

```
'./Donnees_Prevent/Donnees_par_impact/'
```

So I can change my folder location without change my Python code.

Is there a way to do it in Python?

Comment: You can probably use the OS module in python for this. Are you familiar with Linux commands? that might help you with using the OS module, but you can anyday read through the documentation.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Or should your program just take an argument specifying where this directory is?

Comment: I don't use Linux on my computer, I use Windows. Do you know the OS command to do it ?

Comment: I would like to send my folder to someone so he can use the code whitout change it. And whatever is the location of the folder, the code could be run.

Comment: So you are trying to convert absolute paths to relative paths? There is `os.path.relpath(path, start = os.curdir)` but the actual answer depends on how you're going to use it.